# C++: Output data stored in List container to a text file

Tags: c++, list, export, ofstream

I am trying to export `infeasible` to a text file, however the code does not compile with the following syntax error:
no match for call to '(std::list) (std::list::iterator&)'|

```
    list<solution> feasible, infeasible;

    for(list<solution>::iterator it = merged.begin(); it != merged.end(); it++) {
        mutation(*it, input);
        if(it->feasible) 
            feasible.push_front(*it);
        else {
            infeasible.push_front(*it);
            ofstream outfile;
            outfile.open("output.txt");
            for(list<solution>::iterator it2 = infeasible.begin(); it2 != infeasible.end(); it2++)
                outfile<<infeasible(*it2)<<std::endl;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: You seem to be writing the file again from scratch every time you find something infeasible. Is that intentional? Why?

Comment: Yes, that is intentional. Error: no match for call to '(std::list<solution>) (std::list<solution>::iterator&)'|

Comment: Presumably on `infeasible(*it2)`? What is that supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

***Preliminary remark:***  for every item in `merged`, you write a new file with the same name,  overwriting the previous one.   If you want to avoid this and always add the new output to the end of the same file, use:

```
        outfile.open("output.txt", ios::app);
```

**Assuming that** class `solution` contains at least a member `feasible`, that function `mutation()` is properly defined, that `merged` is a `list<solution>` and that you have defined an inserter for `solution`:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const solution &s ) {
   return os<<"??";   //t.b.d.
}
```

**Then** you could change your code slightly to make it compile:

```
   for(auto it = merged.begin(); it != merged.end(); it++) {
        mutation(*it, input);
        if(it->feasible) 
            feasible.push_front(*it);
        else {
            infeasible.push_front(*it);
            ofstream outfile;
            outfile.open("output.txt", ios::app);
            for(auto it2 = infeasible.begin(); it2 != infeasible.end(); it2++)
                outfile<<*it2<<std::endl;   // use directly *it2
        }
    }
```

Comment: It compiles, however I cannot seem to assign a value to "os" to be written to a file output.txt. Currently, it is printing "??" as expected.